# Set timer automatically increase

Tags: android

I want to ask the logic to implement the timer clock like the following format: "**00:01 -> 00:02 -> 00:03 -> 00:04 ... -> 00:59 -> 01:00**". It increases every second after that auto update the `TextView`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use Timer or CountDownTimer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you tried so far, Don't ever ask any question in that format. Anyway,

Add below code in your `xml` file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/timerVal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="@string/startButtonLabel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="@string/pauseButtonLabel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add below java code in in `MainActivity.java` or other Java `Class` File :

```
private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;

    private TextView timerValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
```

Adjust timer logic based on your requirements. Hope this is helpfull for you.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact answer that i'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome . Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Thread counttime = new Thread() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //update your textview here
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
};

counttime.start();
```

you can adjust sleep time changing value of

> Thread.sleep(1000);

1000 miliseconds is 1 second

for more details  refer official documentations - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html